# Using Gamin instead of FAM in PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, pecl

PHP provides an interesting interface to the FAM library through [a PECL package](http://pecl.php.net/package/fam). Unfortunately, I cannot install FAM or the corresponding PECL package because it conflicts (according to apt) with Gamin on Ubuntu. Apparently, Gamin and FAM use the same API. Does anyone know of a way I can utilize Gamin from PHP? I was thinking I might be able to just change some references in the PECL package source to get it to work with Gamin's duplicate API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gamin provides FAM equivalents. You don't need to change anything.

Comment: Thanks. Just figured this out. Heh. It looks like getting this to work is as simple as installing the correct apt packages. On Ubuntu you want to have `gamin`, `libgamin-dev`, and `libgamin0` installed. I was missing `libgamin-dev`. After you install those packges, PECL will install and compile FAM support flawlessly.